# Если есть dll а проект не находит lib файл (QT)

Tags: c++, qt, dll, lib

Не понимаю почему проекту нужно именно lib (ну и в целом в этой теме особо ничего не понимаю).

Пример:
В `.pro` файл записано:

`CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-test-release/release/ -ltest`

и в этой папке(`build-test-release/release`) находится `test.dll`. А он все равно ругается:

```
cannot open input file "test.lib"
```

Что нибудь можно сделать что бы отвязаться от необходимости поиска либ-файлов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из того что узнал, так это `.lib` файлы нужны только msvc.

Выход из ситуации - генерация lib-файла из dll.
Хорошо описано в этом сайте: [Генерация .lib из DLL с помощью Visual Studio](http://xbb.uz/dev/Gjenjeracija-.lib-iz-DLL-s-pomoshhju-Visual-Studio).
В двух словах:

1. Запускаем `Visual Studio Command Prompt`
2. Вводим команду: `dumpbin /exports C:\path\to\test.dll`
3. Создаем файл: `test.def`
4. Первой строчкой вводим слово: `EXPORTS`
5. Копируем из вывода команды 2 четвертый столбец(имена ф-ций которые хранит dll) и вставляем в файл `test.def` со второй строчки. Сохраняем файл.
6. Вводим команду: `lib /def:C:\path\to\test.def /out:C:\path\to\test.lib /machine:x64`
7. Файл `test.lib` создан

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй абсолютные пути прописать

```
LIBS += -L"E:/pr/testdll/Debug/debug" -ltest
INCLUDEPATH += "E:/QtProj/test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не нужно делать. При сборке .dll не нужны.